# Optimize Collision Detection C++

Tags: c++, optimization

This is a program take input as form of

2MU133 -34.94 -69.13 0.468 -0.900
which first one is ID of a car, second one is x-Pos, third one is y-Pos, forth one is x-Velocity and fifth is y-Velocity. Once the distance between two car reach 10, they collide and vaporize.
My program run correctly but I am wondering if there is any modification I should do so it can run faster on large scale of data because now it is kind of slow.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::make_tuple;
using std::tuple;
using std::vector;
using std::get;
using std::sqrt;
using std::sort;
bool tupleCompare(tuple<string, string, double> first,
                  tuple<string, string, double> second)
{
    return get<2>(first) < get<2>(second);
}

tuple<string, string, double> willCollide(tuple<string, double, double, double, double> car1,
                                          tuple<string, double, double, double, double> car2)
{
    double posDifX = get<1>(car1) - get<1>(car2);
    double posDifY = get<2>(car1) - get<2>(car2);
    double velDifX = get<3>(car1) - get<3>(car2);
    double velDifY = get<4>(car1) - get<4>(car2);

    double a = velDifX * velDifX + velDifY * velDifY;
    double b = 2 * (posDifX * velDifX + posDifY * velDifY);
    double c = posDifX * posDifX + posDifY * posDifY - 100;
    double possibleSol = b * b - 4 * a * c; // b^2-4ac
    double sol1, sol2;
    if ((a == 0) || possibleSol < 0)
    { //check for a = 0 or b^2-4ac < 0
        return make_tuple("0", "0", 0);
    }
    else
    {
        sol1 = (-b + sqrt(possibleSol)) / (2 * a);
        sol2 = (-b - sqrt(possibleSol)) / (2 * a);
        if (sol1 <= sol2 && sol1 > 0)
        {
            return make_tuple(get<0>(car1), get<0>(car2), sol1);
        }
        else if (sol2 <= sol1 && sol2 > 0)
        {
            return make_tuple(get<0>(car1), get<0>(car2), sol2);
        }
        else
        {
            return make_tuple("0", "0", 0);
        }
    }

}

bool containString(vector<string> colliedCars, string check)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < colliedCars.size(); i++)
    {
        if (check == colliedCars[i])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    vector<tuple<string, double, double, double, double> > collectionOfCars; //All info of cars
    vector<tuple<string, string, double> > collision; //all possible collision
    vector<string> hasCollided; //store ID of cars already collid
    vector<tuple<string, string, double> > collisionResult; //result of collision
    string ID;
    double xPos, yPos, xVel, yVel;
    while (cin >> ID >> xPos >> yPos >> xVel >> yVel)
    { //read in info about cars
        collectionOfCars.push_back(make_tuple(ID, xPos, yPos, xVel, yVel));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < collectionOfCars.size(); i++)
    { //test for time of collision for different pairs of cars
        for (int j = i + 1; j < collectionOfCars.size(); j++)
        {
            tuple<string, string, double> result =
                    willCollide(collectionOfCars[i], collectionOfCars[j]);
            if (get<0>(result) != "0")
            {
                collision.push_back(result);
            }
        }
    }
    sort(collision.begin(), collision.end(), tupleCompare);
    for (int k = 0; k < collision.size(); k++)
    {
        if (!containString(hasCollided, get<0>(collision[k]))
                && !containString(hasCollided, get<1>(collision[k])))
        {
            hasCollided.push_back(get<0>(collision[k]));
            hasCollided.push_back(get<1>(collision[k]));
            collisionResult.push_back(collision[k]);
        }
    }
    cout << "there are " << collectionOfCars.size() << " vehicles" << "\n";
    cout << "collision report" << "\n";
    if (collisionResult.size() == 0)
    {
        cout << "none" << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < collisionResult.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << "at " << get<2>(collisionResult[i]) << " "
                    << get<0>(collisionResult[i]) << " collided with "
                    << get<1>(collisionResult[i]) << "\n";
        }
    }
    cout << "the remaining vehicles are" << "\n";
    if (hasCollided.size() == collectionOfCars.size())
    {
        cout << "none" << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < collectionOfCars.size(); j++)
        {
            if (!containString(hasCollided, get<0>(collectionOfCars[j])))
            {
                ID = get<0>(collectionOfCars[j]);
                xPos = get<1>(collectionOfCars[j]);
                yPos = get<2>(collectionOfCars[j]);
                xVel = get<3>(collectionOfCars[j]);
                yVel = get<4>(collectionOfCars[j]);
                cout << ID << " " << xPos << " " << yPos << " " << xVel << " "
                        << yVel << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please copy and paste your code directly into your question. It makes it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: Square root is typically fairly slow. For a case like this, it may be faster to find when distance squared drops below 100 rather than when distance drops below 10.

Comment: There is a requirement to output time cars collide so I will have to use square root in quadratic formula

Comment: `const &` to avoid all that copying. And you should not overuse tuples ... `struct` ure your data.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to C++. So I am wondering what problems will be caused by using too much tuples compare to struct?

Answer (score -1):

You're employing an `O(n^2)` algorithm, where `n` is the number of cars. That is, for each car you check every other car and check for collisions. You can do better by employing a [quad tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), which turns it into `O(n * log(n))`. That should dramatically increase performance for large `n`.

Note that there are lots of other spatial indexing data structures, but the quad tree is relatively easy to implement among all such data structures.

Comment: I am wondering if I keep O(n^2) so I will still compare pairs of cars. Is there any other part I can modify to make code run faster?

Comment: Well, there are various tweaks like taking things by `const &`, changing the `ID` of the car into an integer instead of a `string`, etc

Comment: How does using a Quad Tree eliminate the need for each car to be compared against all other cars? What's the logical ordering for each car stored in this Quad Tree?

Comment: Once all cars are in the quad tree, then for a given car, you can apply the `query` operation to find all neighboring cars. This operation is `O(log n)`. Doing this for all cars results in `O(n log n)`. Putting all cars in the quad tree also takes `O(n log n)`. When the distribution of cars is not terribly concentrated, you'll find a relatively small number of neighboring cars, for which you can do your collision tests.

Comment: The logical ordering is their position.

Comment: The problem is quadtree is not included in the standard library. If I want to use it, I will have to implement one which will make my code more complicated. This creates a problem -- this code has to be turned in only in one .cpp file.